# Do I lock code in both threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, locking

new to programming in threads and using locks
So I've 2 threads - one reading vlaues from COM port - the other one controlling a stepper motor

in one thread

> ```
>         if stepperb_value != 0: #if stepperb non-zero
>             if stepperb_value > 0: # if positive value
>                 self.step_fine(10,11,12,13,step_delay) #step forward
>             else:
>                 self.step_fine(13,12,11,10,step_delay) #step backwards
>             if abs(stepperb_value) != 100:
>                 time.sleep(10*step_delay*((100/abs(stepperb_value))-1))
> ```

(I need to prevent a change to stepperb causing a divide by zero error on last line)

in the other thread thats reading the values from the COM port

> ```
>             if 'stepperb' in dataraw:
>                 outputall_pos = dataraw.find('stepperb')
>                 sensor_value = dataraw[(1+outputall_pos+len('stepperb')):].split()
>                 print "stepperb" , sensor_value[0]
>                 if isNumeric(sensor_value[0]):
>                     stepperb_value =  int(max(-100,min(100,int(sensor_value[0]))))
> ```

Where (and what sort of locks) do I need - the first thread is time sensitive so that needs to have priority

regards

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using only CPython, you have another possibility (for now).

As CPython has the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock), assignments are atomic. So you can pull `stepperb_value` into a local variable in your motor control thread before using it and use the local variable instead of the global one.

Note that you'd be using an implementation detail here. Your code possibly won't run safely on other python implementations such as Jython or IronPython. Even on CPython, the behaviour might change in the future, but I don't see the GIL go away before Python 5 or something.

Comment: I'm liking this (As  i don't have to learn to implement locks :) ) but why is it potentially not safe - once I've taken a copy of the global variable into a local one, surely the local one can't be changed by the the other threads actions?

Comment: @SimpleSi: it's potentially unsafe because the fact that assignments are atomic (that copying the global value into a local is atomic) is an implementation detail of CPython, not a language guarantee.  Up to you, but I don't think "I don't have to learn to implement locks" is a good idea -- good programmers are aware of multithreading issues and know how to write safe code.

Comment: I'm not a good programmer :)  Ok, then I'll try and do this properly :)  What sort of locks do I need remembering that I don't mind delaying thread2 so I want thread1 to have any priority available.

Comment: @SimpleSi the problem is, once thread1 gets the lock, thread2 won't be able to take it away from thread1. So basically its probably the best to take the same measures as I described and surround the assignment from/to the local variable by locks. Aside from that, have a look at Guy L:s answer, Queues are a viable option!

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to lock around any series of accesses that expects `stepperb_value` not to change in the series.  In your case, that would be the entire motor control block you posted.  Similarly, you should lock around the entire assignment to `stepperb_value` in the COM port thread, to ensure that the write is atomic, and does not happen while the first thread holds the lock (and expects the value not to change).

Answer (score 2):

Well, your critical variable is `stepperb_value` so that's what should be "guarded":

I suggest you to use Queue which takes care for all the synchronization issues (consumer/producer pattern). Also events and conditions can be a suitable solution:

http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/